# Normal booting mode issue

Tags: boot, graphics

I am using the GTX 750 graphics card to use the twin output ( monitor and projector ).. Now the PC was not booting in the normal mode,  as the system booting only in the Recovery mode. So that I could not able to do administration settings to setup the PC. Kindly please help me solve this issue

Regards,
Sridhar

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use? What you did before getting recovery mode?

Comment: Iam using Ubuntu 14.04. And I getting only blank screen when booting